# toggle overflow:auto attrbitute on a div from a button JQuery

Tags: jquery, overflow

I have a container div on a comments form which can vary in length - so i have set it to a min height of 300px with overflow:auto set so it gets a scrollbar so that some of the content can be seen.

I want to add a buttonlink which  I can click to expand the whole div, removing the height and overflow and swapping the button image to indicate that the div is "expended".

```
.jointheconversation 
{
border: 1px solid #78787b;
overflow: auto;
height: 300px;
```

}

Note i do not want to hide the whole div initially, so cannot just "toggle" the element using jquery

can anyone give me code to do this in jquery?
skeleton here: http://jsfiddle.net/nogribin/qrt8t/14/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('.jointheconversation').css({
        height:'auto',
        overflow:auto
    });
});
```

This will set the height and overflow to `auto` when the button is clicked, allowing users to see all the content without needing to scroll.

Comment: thanks daniel . I managed to hack a solution together before seeing your reply: http://jsfiddle.net/nogribin/qrt8t/24/ Hattip